# django logout or delete use session after user is deleted

Tags: python, django

Lets say I have a user `abc` logged in to my django system. Now when I see my profile or any action that requires authentication I can do it.

And now from my database I deleted the user `abc` and tried to access the view that requires authentication or some validation then it goes in infinite redirect loop.

But when I logout the deleted user by `/account/logount` and access the view its fine.

How can I logout even after the user is deleted.

How can I delete the authentication after user is deleted ?

Comment: may be u can delete relevant entries from `django_session` table in pre_delete signal of user model

Answer (score 0):

If you are using the default of django sessions you can go and delete the session from the database. These are stored in the `django_session` table.

Edit:

There is a django admin command to clear all expired sessions if you don't want to modify your database more. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-clearsessions

Edit 2:

You can also delete the session cookie in the browser by opening the developer tools and going to the cookie storage and finding the session cookie and deleting it there.

Comment: its preity complex method. I want if there is any kind of signal that is fired and delete the session related to the user and logout the user

Comment: I think I misunderstood your question then. This should be taken care of automatically when the user is deleted through the ORM. I thought you were doing it manually for some reason.

Comment: I am doing it manually. I am deleting the user from my database and now when the user is deleted I want all the session related to it should be deleted and the user should be logged out

Answer (score -1):

After you delete your user in your code call

```
from django.contrib.auth import logout 
logout(request)
```

Comment: Yes I am talking server side. In your view

Comment: suppose I delete the user and look for the profile of deleted user.. then should I write the logout function in profile view ? I want when the user is deleted from the databse it should be logout automaticaly

Comment: Then in your logout view you would need to add what he has posted above.

Comment: It depends on what function is deleting the user. Is it triggered by the user in a view? Or is it some server side cleanup process?

Comment: Delete the sessions from your database too then that are related to the user. Likely that will cause them to have to log in again.